# Send SMS Message to multiple recipients in Swift

Tags: ios, swift2, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I want to send a single message to multiple recipients using **MFMessageComposeViewController**, I am unable to add the second and so on recipients

here's my code :

```
@IBAction func sendSms(sender: AnyObject) {

        if (MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText())
        {
            let controller = MFMessageComposeViewController()
            controller.body = self.textView.text
            controller.recipients = [self.phoneField.text!]
            controller.messageComposeDelegate = self
            self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else
        {
            print("Error")
        }
    }

extension MyViewController : MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate 
{
    func messageComposeViewController(_ controller: MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MessageComposeResult)     
    {
            controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)}
    }
}
```

Any Suggestions how can i send it to multiple recipients?

Comment: What is the issue you are facing ? controller.recipients expects an array, you can give the recipient phone numbers as an array to this property

Comment: I am inserting phone number in **textField** and passing it to controller.recipients

Comment: `[controller.recipients = [phone1, phone2 ...]`

Comment: @shallowThought tried 'controller.recipients = ["9999999999,1234516828"]' not working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If user is entering multiple phone numbers in your textfield then you need to prompt the user to separate phone numbers using comma (or any other symbol) through which you can separate the string and add it into your array, then pass that array in `controller.recipients`

here is an example

```
if (MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText())
        {
            let controller = MFMessageComposeViewController()
            controller.body = self.textView.text
            let phoneNumberString = "123456789,987654321,2233445566"
            let recipientsArray = phoneNumberString.components(separatedBy: ",")
            controller.recipients = recipientsArray
            controller.messageComposeDelegate = self
            self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else
        {
            print("Error")
        }
```

Comment: @rajat do u face any black color view presenting while multiple contacts selected from your app??

Comment: @Ramakrishna, No, I haven't faced such issue.

Comment: hoo.. ok. I'm loading around 200 contacts at a time into the message composer from my app. To load all contacts it taking time and at that time it showing a black color view. This is my problm.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add multiple recipients then you can write this...

here is my code...

```
if (MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText()) 
{
    let composeVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()
    composeVC.messageComposeDelegate = self

    // Configure the fields of the interface.
    composeVC.recipients = ["4085551212","8597485365","2564756984"]
    composeVC.body = "Hello from California!"

    // Present the view controller modally.
    self.presentViewController(composeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func messageComposeViewController(controller: MFMessageComposeViewController,
                              didFinishWithResult result: MessageComposeResult)
{
    // Check the result or perform other tasks.

    // Dismiss the message compose view controller.
    controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```